# ZF2 Have all routes resolve to one controller and action

Tags: php, angularjs, zend-framework2

I'm trying to develop and single page app with AngularJS and ZF2. I'm having trouble with the routing.  My idea is to have routes like /:controller/:action resolve to a single action.  I've read the docs and tried the different routing types.

My idea is to have all /:controller/:action to resolve to App\IndexController\IndexAction so only the Angular init code is returned.  After the initial page has loaded, Angular will send a secondary request to /template/:controller/:action to retrieve the template and /api/:controller/:action to gather to template's data.
Below is an example of the Regex route I attempted to make work.

```
'app' => array(
    'type'    => 'Regex',
    'options' => array(
        'regex'    => '/(?[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*\/[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)',
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller'    => 'App\Controller\IndexController',
            'action'        => 'index',
        ),
        'spec' => '/'
    ),
    'may_terminate' => true,
),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a `Segment` route:

```php
'app' => array(
    'type' => 'Segment',
    'options' => array(
        'route' => ':controller-fake/:action-fake',
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'App\Controller\Index',
            'action' => 'index',
        ),
    ),
),
```

Comment: :controller-fake and :action-fake were the parts I were missing when trying with a Segment route.

Answer (score 2):

Why you just don't define 3 major routes of segment type. See the code below:

```
'all' => [
    'type'    => 'Segment',
    'options' => [
        'route'    => '/app/[:controller[/:action]]',
        'constraints' => [
            'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
            'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
        ],
        'defaults' => [
            'controller' => 'App\Controller\IndexController',
            'action' => 'index'
        ],
    ],
],

'template' => [
    'type'    => 'Segment',
    'options' => [
        'route'    => '/template/[:controller[/:action]]',
        'constraints' => [
            'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
            'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
        ],
        'defaults' => [],
    ],
],

'api' => [
    'type'    => 'Segment',
    'options' => [
        'route'    => '/api/[:controller[/:action]]',
        'constraints' => [
            'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
            'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
        ],
        'defaults' => [],
    ],
]
```